# Prevent CodeMirror json-lint from linting empty input

Tags: javascript, codemirror, jsonlint, ui-codemirror

I'm putting together a quick CodeMirror input for JSON and to make sure the user doesn't mess things up, I'm using the json-lint addon. My issue is that immediately on render the empty CodeMirror input is displaying a lint error. I understand that an empty input doesn't constitute valid JSON, but I'd rather it only runs when input has been made.

I'm using the `addon/lint/json-lint.js` add-on, which in turn is using the [`jsonlint`](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) package.

**JS**

```
var jsonConfig = {
    mode:              'application/json',
    lineNumbers:       true,
    lint:              true,
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    gutters:           ['CodeMirror-lint-markers']
};

$('.json textarea').each(function (pos, el) {
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(el, jsonConfig);
});
```

**Example empty input results:**
[image]

**Lint message:**
[image]

I can't see anything in the docs to disable linting for empty inputs. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

```
    var editor_json = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("textAreaId"), {
       lineNumbers: true,
       mode: "application/json",
       gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
       lint: true,
       theme: '<yourThemeName>'
    });

    //on load check if the textarea is empty and disable validation
    editor_json.setOption("lint", editor_json.getValue().trim() );

    //once changes happen, if the textarea gets filled up again re-enable the validation
    editor_json.on("change", function(cm, change) {
        editor_json.setOption("lint", editor_json.getValue().trim() );
    });

    ///sometimes you need to refresh the CodeMirror instance to fix alignment problems or some other glitch
    setTimeout(function(){
       editor_json.refresh();
    },0);
```

So in short:

```
editor_json.setOption("lint", editor_json.getValue().trim() );
```

Which is translated to:

< yourCodeMirrorInstance >.setOption('< yourOption >',< true/false or any required value >)

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

you could set a default value to the textarea like this

```
{\n\t\n}
```

you would have something like this

```
{

}
```