# Nuxtjs/Vuejs Watchers running into endless loop due to change in the values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, onchange, codemirror

I am developing a `Nuxtjs/Vuejs` application to convert the `XML->JSON` and vice versa. Users can provide the values to the `textarea` and these `textareas` are managed by `CodeMirror`.

The `textarea` is bonded to `V-model` from the `Vex Store`. I have added `Watchers` on these `Vuex` state variables so whenever they change the values I want to convert the respective data to a different format. I.e if `XML` value changes then `XML` needs to be converted to `JSON`. Similarly if `JSON` value changes then `JSON` needs to be converted to `XML`.

When I copy-paste the `XML` into `XML textarea` then for the first time it works perfectly but I make any modification and try to introduce some `Syntax` error in `XML` then I run into the issue where the `watchers` starts calling each other and endup in endless loops.

I have provided the sample code within `CodeSandbox`: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-g14zd?file=/pages/index.vue

Steps to recreate the issue:

1. Provide the `Sample XML` in the `XML Area`:

```
<root>
<name>Batman</name>
</root>
```

We get the output as: `CONVERT TO JSON-LD` within the `JSON textarea`

2. Now make the modification to the same `XML` within the `XML Textarea` by removing some `anchor` tab (`</>`)

Now both `textarea` are populated with `Error Message` but in reality I want only the `JSON` area to be populated with `Error Message` indicating whats wrong in XML and `Modified XML` should be as it is within the `XML Area`.

If you observe the `Console` then you can see that I am running into a `cyclic issue` due to the `watchers`. I want to call the `jsonConverter` whenever the `XML` value changes within the `XML Editor` and same vice versa but I do not want to get into `XMLConverter` after `converting` to `JSON`.

Can someone please explain to me how can I avoid this issue? I am running out of all ideas as I am unable to get the `onChange` for the `CodeMirror` directly I am using the `Watchers`. If someone has any idea or solution it would be really great as I have spent more than a day to resolve this but ended up with nothing.

CodeSandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-g14zd?file=/pages/index.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that your JSON and XML values are being controlled in too many places. The `v-model`s, the watchers, and the CodeMirror events.

I have changed your code and made CodeMirror the main controller of the values. You can see the result here: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-69498468-c2uql?file=/pages/index.vue)

To prevent the parsing loop, I've compared the new values with the ones saved in the store. If they are the same, then the value has been set by ourselves. If they differ, then the user has changed it and we should try to parse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking the code and providing the response. This seems like the best approach to handle everything. Thanks again for the answer. Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Everything is working perfectly. I have one small doubt: If you observe the `JSON Textarea` the `lint` operation is performed even for the `Empty` values. Is there a way to avoid lint operations on `Empty JSON Area`? I tried the method mentioned here but its not working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658428/7584240

Comment: I have updated the codesanbox to handle the issue you described.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction. Its. now working as expected.